# What is the difference between "face a challenge" and "face up to a challenge"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference between *face a challenge* and *face up to a challenge*? For example:

> The teacher is going to **face the challenge** of teaching a disobedient class.
>
> The teacher is going to **face up to the challenge** of teaching a disobedient class.

Does the second sentence imply that the teacher will have to deal with the class bravely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Face a challenge" has no implications about how the person in the situation is going to deal with it, simply that there is a challenge coming their way.  They may confront it, pretend it doesn't exist, run away, etc.

"Face up to a challenge" implies that the person is going to attempt to overcome it.

[From Merriam-Webster][1]

[1]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face%20up%20to#:~:text=%3A%20to%20deal%20with%20(something%20bad,face%20up%20to%20our%20fears.

Answer (score 0):

According to the cambridge dictionary:

face:

> If you face a problem, or a problem faces you, you have to deal with it

face up to:

> to accept that a **difficult** situation exists

*emphasis mine*

So you are right in saying that the second sentence implies a higher degree of difficulty.

Comment: _Face the challenge_ just indicates that the challenge exists. If someone is going to _face up to_ a challenge, they are intending to confront it bravely.